# Content Search WebPart - get latest changed documents

Tags: sharepoint-online

I use the Content Search WebPart and want a query that gives me the latest changed documents, not the sites like .aspx, only documents. What do I write?

Answer (score 0):

Set Sorting to `LastModifiedTime` -> `Descending`.

To get documents, but not `.aspx`files you can use:

```
(IsDocument:"True") Path:{SiteCollection.URL} NOT FileExtension:aspx
```

This will get all non-aspx documents from the current site collection ordered by modified time